# Как с точки зрения компилятора представлены пакеты параметров в шаблонах и развертывание пакетов параметров в отдельные имена

Tags: c++, c++11

Читал про шаблонны с переменным числом параметров в c++ - смутила фраза:

> Разъясняю своими словами (могу ненароком наврать, но попробую):
>
> Начало объяснения моими словами. **В шаблоне получается один целостный
> тип из множества типов, отданных в функцию. Сам по себе он один тип.
> Просто состоит из составных частей, где каждая часть является отданным
> в функцию типом.** Вот так и получается, что тип для шаблона будет один.
> Этот один тип и назван пакетом (упаковкой, паком). Как угодно можно
> назвать. Просто внутри себя он полностью наполнен типами. А внутри
> функции объявлена переменная, тип которой и есть список типов (пакет).
> Так как с троеточия начинать объявление типов нельзя, то троеточие
> внутри функции указано после типа (справа от Args), а само по себе
> троеточие обозначает, что это не отдельная переменная одного
> конкретного типа, а принадлежность этой переменной к одному из типов
> внутри пакета.
>
> Конец объяснения моими словами.

Источник:
http://ci-plus-plus-snachala.ru/?p=4100

Comment: *"В шаблоне получается один целостный тип из множества типов ... Сам по себе он один тип ... Этот один тип и назван пакетом"* Глупость написана, насколько я понимаю. Parameter-pack'и не являются типами.

Comment: Спасибо, насчет стиля вопросов понял, а насчет пакетов, не могли бы Вы разъяснить по-подробнее, желательно в виде ответа. Спасибо.

Comment: Честно говоря, меня эта фраза тоже смутила. И она очень далека от реальности тип и три точки - это такая форма записи последовательности. Но вопрос из заголовка тоже какой-то мутный. С точки зрения компиляторов это может быть что-ни вроде пачки ссылок на префиксное дерево например. Ээ, стоп! Вторая часть этого вопроса касается функций с переменным числом аргументов (как в С). Это совершенно различные сущности по сравнению с шаблоном с пакетом параметров. Хотя и там, и там, используются три точки. Про "повышения типа аргумента по умолчанию" - лучше задать отдельный вопрос.